# Do I have to include texts twice in HTML and JSON-LD for Google?

Tags: seo, google, json-ld

Is it possible in 2021 to avoid having to output article, job posting, event, etc. texts twice - in HTML and the JSON-LD structure - while keeping Google happy? Google still does not support linked JSON-LD via `link` tag, but are there any other solutions? My problem is that having article texts twice bloats the page and users must download something that is twice as large (gzip aside).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google supports three types of markup for structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/intro-structured-data):

- JSON-LD
- Microdata
- RDFa

Of those, only JSON-LD requires that you duplicate the content.  Both Microdata and RDFa can mark up the content where it lays in the page.

Schema.org has examples for every type of schema in all three markup flavors.  For example for the [review schema](https://schema.org/Review), there are tabs on the example code that show you how to apply the schema using any of the supported markup languages.  Here is a screenshot showing the microdata markup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I knew about Microdata and it's what I am using now for a large site, but I thought Google will slowly deprecate that in favor of JSON-LD which they mention as recommended format.

Comment: JSON-LD has some "separation of concerns" advantages in that it is less fragile when a page is modified and easier to add to a page written an opaque framework.   I believe it is recommend because of that and not because the others will be deprecated.

Comment: Search engines may also have difficulty corroborating the semantics of JSON-LD when it is referencing content that is far down a page, like in long form articles. This is because of the far distance between the semantic markup and the actual citation of the entity/embodiment. It _can_ be done by referencing CSS selectors, however, I still argue that microdata is more reliable for this.